# What urlfetch limits apply to Python backends on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to be moving around files of up to 100 MB or so. If I'm reading the docs correctly, I'll need to use a backend to have any hope of not hitting per-request limits. Will the backend quotas allow me to do this, or do backends only drop the time limits, not the bandwidth limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New limits for `fetch()` requests are about 32MB. However, if your source HTTP server supports "range" requests, you may easily fetch your files in parts and then combine them back in order.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's streaming audio, so that won't work. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: @lenik wondering if you could provide some sample code on specifying
 a range on urlfetch? I've tried the following and it doesn't work: response = urlfetch.fetch(url,headers={'Range':'bytes=1-2'}).content